# Checkstyles with SonarLint rules?

Tags: intellij-idea, checkstyle, sonarlint

Can i use checkstyles in IDE while development with sonar rules, so that while programming itself the rules take care of sonar issues ?

I have seen checkstyles doing auto-indentation while typing code. Is there a way to configure it with sonar rules so that while coding itself the sonar rules kick in, instead of manually having to run the report ?

Answer (score 1):

First off all, IntelliJ IDEA has a lot of [code inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) already included.
If these are not enough, and you need Sonar/SonarLint, there is a [SonarLint plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint).
In addition, you might also be interested in [OpenRewrite](https://docs.openrewrite.org/)'s [Common static analysis issue remediation](https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/popular-recipe-guides/common-static-analysis-issue-remediation) which can automatically fix issues for you.